# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mnemonic'

Tags: python-3.x

## Jupyter Notebook

I wrote `!pip install mnemonic`

This shows that `Requirement already satisfied: mnemonic in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (0.19)`

Then I code:

```
import mnemonic
```

It gives this error message:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mnemonic'`

I do not know what is going on. Why was this module not found!

Comment: usually this mean that your python and pip are pointing to different things

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo can you suggest a way to fix this? Is there any guide to fix it?

Comment: make sure that your pip3 put the package in the same directory that your paython3 will get. Usually pip3 and python3 work together, but I think is your config problem

Comment: Run the import outside Jupyter, does it work? If so, then you have Jupyter using a different Python interpreter/kernel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this:

```py
import sys

from pprint import pprint

pprint(sys.path)
```

and check if it includes your path from pip "c:\python39\lib\site-packages".

If it's not in the list then you can include it with:

```py
sys.path.insert("c:\python39\lib\site-packages")
```

```py
sys.path.append("c:\python39\lib\site-packages")
```

Comment: It did not included then I wrote what you proposed i got this error ```TypeError: insert expected 2 arguments, got 1```

Comment: Oh yea right. sys.path is a list so it has to be ```sys.path.insert(0, "c:\python39\lib\site-packages")``` or ```sys.path.append("c:\python39\lib\site-packages")```